# Two-Terminal Passive Analog Component Tester Using the DE1-SoC Development Board

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, intel-fpga, intel

I am having hard time understanding this problem. I have to draw a Level 1 block diagram for this system. I really appreciated it if somebody can help me. I am new to DE1-Soc.

use the Intel  DE1-SoC development board, additional custom circuitry (Bread board) and possibly an external source for input waveforms to implement a system that will allow any of four possible types of two-terminal passive analog components to be connected to it, and identify the connected two-terminal as being one of the four types. The four types of components are as follows:

1. Resistors
2. Capacitors (non-electrolytic only)
3. Inductors
4. Diodes

test results for a particular connected component should be displayed on the seven segment LED.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just ignore the dev board at first. You just need to figure out how you're going to distinguish between the types of component, how you're going to measure each type, and how you're going to get the right circuitry switched in for each type.

Comment: I am thinking about building a circuit that test each component at a time and gives parameters to the specific components to display.

Comment: You're getting ahead of yourself if you just want to draw a block diagram.

Comment: Do you understand how the myriad uC-based testers work? You're going to have to replicate what they do, but in an FPGA.

Comment: No, I never had any experience with myriad microcontroller based tester.  Can you please some link that i refered it and learn more about it.

Comment: Hello Mr. Dave Tweed, Thank you for you suggestion. If you have any web link that you can refer me about Myriad microcontroller based tester than it would be really great. Thank you for your time.